# Upgrading to Powerlevel10k - Extra space at the end of line

Tags: zsh, theme, oh-my-zsh

When I switch from [`powerlevel9k`](https://github.com/Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k) to [`powerlevel10k`](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k), some extra space appears at the end of each line.

[image]

How can I remove this space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/issues/132#issuecomment-514592283):

> This difference is due to a bug Powerlevel9k that is too severe to
>   emulate in Powerlevel10k.
>
> If you want your right prompt to be at the edge of the screen without
>   indentation, add `ZLE_RPROMPT_INDENT=0` to your `~/.zshrc` and restart
>   zsh. The default value of this parameter is `1`, hence the space you are
>   seeing. This parameter is respected by all prompts except
>   Powerlevel9k.